# вызов функции из php-файла с помощью ajax при загрузке страницы

Tags: php, ajax

есть файлы file1.php и file2.php. как при загрузке первого файла передать ajax-ом значение переменной второму файлу и в теле первого файла разместить результат исполнения второго файла?

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>

<script>
    function collapsElement(id) {
        if ( document.getElementById(id).style.display != "none" ) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
        }
    }

    function changeArrows(id) {
        if ( document.getElementById(id).className != "arrow_down" ) {
            document.getElementById(id).className = 'arrow_down';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).className = 'arrow_up';
        }
    }
 </script>

 <style type="text/css">
    .arrow_up{
        background-position: right;
        background-image: url('/bitrix/templates/darshan/img/arrow-up.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 16px;
    }

    .arrow_down{
        background-position: right;
        background-image: url('/bitrix/templates/darshan/img/arrow-down.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 16px;
    }
 </style>


    <?$divIdCount = 1;?>

    <div class="news-list">
        <?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem){?>     
            <article class="row post type-post status-publish format-standard entry category-article">

                <div class="large-9 medium-8 small-9 columns">

                    <div id="element<?=$divIdCount?>" style="display: none; margin-left: 25px;">
                        <section class="entry">
                            <p><?=$arItem["PREVIEW_TEXT"];?></p>

                            <?
                            $props = array();
                            $obj = CIBlockElement::GetList(
                                array("SORT" => "ASC"),
                                array("IBLOCK_ID" => $arResult["ID"], "SECTION_ID" => $arParams["PARENT_SECTION"], "ID" => $arItem["ID"]),
                                array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "PROPERTY_FILE_PATH")
                            );
                            while ($value = $obj->GetNext()) {
                                $props[] = $value;
                            }

                            if (strlen($props[0]["PROPERTY_FILE_PATH_VALUE"]) > 0) {
                                $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:player","",Array(
                                    "PLAYER_TYPE" => "auto",
                                    "USE_PLAYLIST" => "Y",
                                    "PATH" => $props[0]["PROPERTY_FILE_PATH_VALUE"],
                                    "PLAYLIST_DIALOG" => "",
                                    "PROVIDER" => "video",
                                    "STREAMER" => "",
                                    "WIDTH" => "640",
                                    "HEIGHT" => "360",
                                    "PREVIEW" => "",
                                    "SKIN_PATH" => "/bitrix/components/bitrix/player/mediaplayer/skins",
                                    "SKIN" => "bitrix.swf",
                                    "CONTROLBAR" => "bottom",
                                    "WMODE" => "transparent",
                                    "LOGO" => "/logo.png",
                                    "LOGO_LINK" => "http://ваш_сайт.com/",
                                    "LOGO_POSITION" => "bottom-left",
                                    "ADDITIONAL_FLASHVARS" => "",
                                    "WMODE_WMV" => "window",
                                    "SHOW_CONTROLS" => "Y",
                                    "AUTOSTART" => "N",
                                    "REPEAT" => "list",
                                    "VOLUME" => "90",
                                    "MUTE" => "N",
                                    )
                                );
                            }
                            ?>                          
                        </section><!-- /.entry -->
                    </div>

                    <header>
                        <h2 class="title entry-title">
                            <div id="arrows<?=$divIdCount?>" class="arrow_down" onClick="changeArrows('arrows<?=$divIdCount?>')">
                                <a href="javascript:collapsElement('element<?=$divIdCount?>')" rel="nofollow"> <b><?=$arItem["NAME"]?></b> </a>
                            </div>
                        </h2>
                    </header>

                    <?if ($arItem['IBLOCK_SECTION_ID'] != 14):?>
                    <div class="post-meta">
                        <abbr class="date time published updated" title="<?echo $arItem["DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM"]?>"><?echo $arItem["DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM"]?></abbr>
                    </div>
                    <?endif;?>
                </div>


                <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-3 columns">

                    <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"]!="N" && is_array($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])):?>
                        <a href="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>">
                            <img class="thumbnail" src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>" alt="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>" />
                        </a>
                    <?endif?>

                </div>
            </article>

            <?$divIdCount++?>
        <?}?>

        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"]):?>
            <br /><?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?>
        <?endif;?>
    </div>
```

это код всей страницы. в отдельный файл нужно вынести вот этот участок

```
<?
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:player","",Array(
                                        "PLAYER_TYPE" => "auto",
                                        "USE_PLAYLIST" => "Y",
                                        "PATH" => $props[0]["PROPERTY_FILE_PATH_VALUE"],
                                        "PLAYLIST_DIALOG" => "",
                                        "PROVIDER" => "video",
                                        "STREAMER" => "",
                                        "WIDTH" => "640",
                                        "HEIGHT" => "360",
                                        "PREVIEW" => "",
                                        "SKIN_PATH" => "/bitrix/components/bitrix/player/mediaplayer/skins",
                                        "SKIN" => "bitrix.swf",
                                        "CONTROLBAR" => "bottom",
                                        "WMODE" => "transparent",
                                        "LOGO" => "/logo.png",
                                        "LOGO_LINK" => "http://ваш_сайт.com/",
                                        "LOGO_POSITION" => "bottom-left",
                                        "ADDITIONAL_FLASHVARS" => "",
                                        "WMODE_WMV" => "window",
                                        "SHOW_CONTROLS" => "Y",
                                        "AUTOSTART" => "N",
                                        "REPEAT" => "list",
                                        "VOLUME" => "90",
                                        "MUTE" => "N",
                                        )
                                    );
                                }
                                ?>
```

и в элемент массива с ключом "PATH" нужно передать значение из `$props[0]["PROPERTY_FILE_PATH_VALUE"]`

Comment: Необходимо конкретизировать вопрос, добавить код и описание, что получилось и что нет

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что никакой ajax там и не нужен, а просто нужен обычный [include](http://www.php.su/include()) или, что ещё проще, сделать код файла в виде функции и использовать ее.

Comment: @KoVadim, `require_once` или `erquire`? :)

Comment: @Doofy честно говоря, бился пару часов, а путевый код, годный для показа, так и не получился. попробую на словах описать. загружается страница, выполняется, условно говоря, первая половина кода и высчитывается значение переменной. далее, перед выполнением второй половины кода, с помощью ajax значение переменной передается в другой файл и результат выполнения другого файла загружается перед второй половиной кода. надеюсь, так понятнее получилось описать...

Comment: @KoVadim я был бы только рад, если бы все решилось обычным require_once )))

Comment: Тоесть вторую половину кода нужно выполнить уже после загрузки странички, поэтому нужен ajax, верно я понял? В теле первого уже ничего не получится изменить, так как страничка уже загрузится и php превратится в html.

Comment: @Doofy да, получается так. просто результатом выполнения второго файла будет html-код и вот этот код должен быть на первой страничке по середине. надо ajax-ом передать переменную, выполнить код на стороннем файле вместе с это переменной и результат выполнения этого кода отобразить по середине первой страницы

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Как html выглядит, куда что вставлять? Можно всё это и в одном php файле сделать, если через запросы всё идёт

Comment: @Doofy в стороннем файле код плеера, а из первого файла передаем во второй путь к видео. нельзя все сделать в одном файле, потому что первая страница кешируется и если код плеера находится непосредственно на странице, но при выводе страницы их кеша плеер на ней не отображается (такая вот особенность cms). получается, если код плеера на странице, то плеер отображается только если кеш истек и страница исполнилась. после исполнения n-ное количество времени страница грузится из кеша и на ней нет плеера. и мне подсказали, что это можно обойти ajax-ом... если грузить плеер из отдельного файла

Comment: Без разницы где будет исполняемый код php. В запросе можно указать `cache: false`

Comment: @Doofy просто я не могу понять как написать запрос и как его вызвать при загрузке страницы... пока у меня есть один цельный файл, который кеширует сама cms и не показывает плеер. мне нужно этот кусок с плеером вынести в отдельный файл и загружать его ajax-ом

Comment: Если добавишь минимальный код в вопрос, с плейером и  местом куда нужно его вставить, то я подскажу

Comment: @Doofy да, сейчас вставлю весь код с разметкой что куда нужно вынести и что передать. спасибо большое

Comment: В этом же файле сверху `<?php if(isset($_POST['player'])) { ... } ?>`, Внутри весь плейер и отправляем post или get запрос на этот же url с ключём `xhr.send('player=')`. Ответ возвращаем и вставляем в класс `entery`. Вот документация на [xhr](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest). Также можно попробовать использовать meta тег для запрета кеширования странички `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">`

Comment: @Doofy честно, даже не могу сообразить... можно, пожалуйста, примерный код, вставленный в исходник... а я завтра я уже допилю, а то сегодня уже не варит котелок

Comment: Сейчас напишу пример

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю что возвращает `$APPLICATION` и пройдёт ли на него `echo`

Один документ, грузится страничка минуя `isset`, при запросе он срабатывает и возвращает на эту же страничку ответ, который вставляет в `.entry`

<sub>[index.php](http://nowhere)</sub>

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['player'])) {
        echo "<div>player</div>";
        exit();
    }
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <section class='entry'></section>
    </body>

    <script src='script.js'></script>
</html>
```

<sub>[script.js](http://nowhere)</sub>

```js
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send('player=');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        document.querySelector('.entry').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
}
```

---

А также можно попробовать запретить кеширование странички, что лучше, если кроме плейера ничего не грузится.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Cache-Control' content='no-cache'>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: $APPLICATION - это объект класса, он информацию о странице содержит и вспомогательные методы. получается, я код плеера выношу в отдельный файл, а вместо него пишу код <?php ... ?>  ?

Comment: @Ислам, в теории да, только я не вижу где сам плейер вставляется конкретно. Код плейера можно не выносить в отдельный файл, его можно поместить в этот же документ, внутри `if(isset($_POST['player'])) { ... }`. Может объект сам что-то возвращает, я с битрикс не знаком

Comment: весь этот кусок кода и есть код плеера. это компонент для воспроизведения видео самой cms. спасибо большое! завтра буду разбираться. ты задал направление, а то я вообще не знал куда копать)))